# phpmyadmin not found error

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

I am running win7 professional.  I recently installed Visual Studio Community and just discovered that my Wamp did not work.  I reset the port in httpd.conf and now Wamp will start but when I try to open phpmyadmin, I get a HTTP Error 404. How do I fix the 404 error?

Comment: You now need to change the port number of your wamp as it would now be occupied by IIS of your visual studio .net

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using? DoubleClick the WAMPServer icon in the system tray

Comment: How do I change the port for myphpadmin?

Comment: Install WAMPServer3.0.4 and there is a menu item that will do it all for you

Comment: Visual Studio Community probably comes with IIS which is also a web server and will be using port 80. IIS is probably being started automatically and therefore holding port 80 before WAMPServer gets started

Comment: You could try setting IIS to a manual start. Run `services.msc` set World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3svc) to manual instead of automatic start. Then Apache will get a chance at port 80 while you are using Apache